# Minor syntax-highlighting amendment (for perl)

Tags: feature-request

Perl - and I presume other languages - allow for custom delimiters when specifying regular expressions.

Currently the syntax highlighting is fine with:

```perl
if ( $line =~ m/some text/ ) { print $line; }
```

But it doesn't work with;

```perl
if ( $line =~ m,some text, ) { print $line; }
```

e.g: (because it doesn't seem to apply at all on meta!):

[counting instances between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305144/counting-instances-between-two-tags/29305402#29305402)

I know it's pretty minor. But it'd be nice.

Comment: Could you toss a `<!-- language: lang-perl -->` in front of the code blocks to enable syntax highlighting so that we may see it?

Comment: @MichaelT It's actually already there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it is missing the **lang** part (and I don't see syntax highlighting being enabled on the code blocks as it is currently).

Comment: _@Sobrique_ SO uses Google Code Prettify. So requesting fixes should go there. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109

Comment: @MichaelT I've fixed that.

Comment: Google prettify is pretty simplistic (in fact, the [docs](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html#langs) mention that it only works on a subset of Perl). See, for example, `my $size = $#array + 1;` (everything after the `#` is treated as a comment). And as you well know, only perl can parse Perl :)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot have you read the [formal proof](http://www.jeffreykegler.com/Home/perl-and-undecidability)?  `whatever  / 25 ; # / ; die "this dies!";` is particularly problematic depending on if you have `sub whatever() {};` or `sub whatever {};`